# Unable to connect to Database using SQL Developer (not picking up from tnsnames.ora)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, linux-mint, tnsnames

I have installed `Oracle 11g` & `SQL Developer` on my Linux Mint OS.

After setting `ORACLE_PATH` and relevant variable in `.bashrc` file, I am able to connect using `sqlplus`.

> Snapshot of my tnsnames.ora

```
  XE =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
          (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
          )
        )

 EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
            (DESCRIPTION =
              (ADDRESS_LIST =
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
              )
              (CONNECT_DATA =
                (SID = PLSExtProc)
                (PRESENTATION = RO)
              )   
    )
```

had tried with `(HOST = localhost)` too.

I've my localhost and IP address is mentioned in `/etc/hosts` file.

I've configured TNSnames directory to sql developer following below command:

```
tools->Preferences->Database->advanced->Tnsnames Directory (where tnsnames.ora is stored)
```

Set the `ORACLE_HOME` as `:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/`

(Not able to connect to SQL Developer even with SYS/SYSDBA credentials)

Error I receive:

> listener refused the connection ora-12514 listener does not currently know of service requested

I've tried almost every single solution by following posts of:

- Google
- StackOverFlow
- Blogs
- Other solutions

But couldn't solve my issue.

Please don't mark this question as duplicate.
I'm badly stuck at this.

**EDIT**: I'm trying to connect using :

1) Connection Type: Basic ; Role: Default

Hostname: Localhost; Port: 1521; SERVICE_NAME: xe

Error:

> listener refused the connection ora-12514 listener does not currently
>   know of service requested

2) Connection Type: TNS ; Role: Default

Specifying Connect Identifier throws:

> ```
> no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path
> ```

Specifying Network Alias 'XE' (choosing from drop-down menu) throws:

> The network Adapter could not establish the connection

Yet I'm able to access using SYS credentials & custom user credentials from terminal- sqlplus

Comment: Are you using connection type, TNS? Have you tried a direct connection? Simply supply hostname, port, and 'xe' for SID (service ID) in your connection details.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I've updated my question to align with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally**! I am able to connect to database using SQL Developer.

(I had verified that port 1521 is opened 
and was able to ping the localhost with port 1521 
and It was not blocked by Firewall )

Reason I was unable to connect was `No TNS listener` (This I got while trying connect from SQL Command Line)

One thing I understand that running SQL*Plus from terminal does not require TNS Listener to connect.

In order to resolve, I had to replace `HOST` in `Listener.ORA` file.

From

> `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))`

To

> ```
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0) (PORT = 1521))
> ```

And then I restart the listener,

```
lsnrctl stop

lsnrctl start
```

Comment: You can use the bequeath connection type in SQLDev if this happens again, then it too can connect to the db without a listener.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, thanks for information about bequeath! btw I get this error on choosing local/bequeath Connection type from drop-down:
`no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path`